# What to do with the ambiguous 'scanner' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup

The tag [scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scanner) (x7) is quite ambiguously used:

1. scanning pages (like with a flatbed-scanner) x4
2. WiFi/network scanner x1
3. malware/vulnerability scanner x1
4. "content scanner" (scanning a webpage for hyperlinks) x1

The weighting already makes clear that #1 should be what the tag is for. So I would go for the following:

1. retag #2 to [wi-fi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wi-fi)
2. retag #3 to [security](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
3. retag #4 to [url](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) (?)
4. create a tag wiki for the then cleaned-up [scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scanner) tag to make its intention clear (though to my experience only few people even read the excerpt, we could very decently bang their heads against that wall then :)

Any comments/arguments on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following:

- Replaced instances of [scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scanner) that were related to document scanning with a less ambiguous [document-scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-scanner) tag; created a wiki for this new tag.
- Removed [scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scanner) from 2, 3, and 4 that you noted. Retagged 4 with [hyperlinks](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperlinks)
- Added a wiki for [media-scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media-scanner) to help make clear the distinction between it and [document-scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-scanner)
- Left [scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scanner) to die off. Arguably we could make it a synonym of the most popular, but the more descriptive tags will appear in the autocomplete for the text "scanner" at this point, so I think it's best to just leave the ambiguous tag alone and see if it comes back.

Comment: Thanks, eldarerathis -- but by creating the `hyperlinks` tag, you introduced a new issue: we already have an `url` tag, as I pointed out in my question. Shall I open a new Q here, or do you merge/synonymize the two as part of this?

Comment: @Izzy: I don't know. A URL isn't necessarily a hyperlink in all contexts. At a quick glance, I'd be inclined to say that none of the questions in the `url` tag currently would refer to hyperlinks (and FWIW, I didn't create `hyperlinks`, it already existed).

Comment: OK, could be my argument: while a hyperlink may count as URL, a URL not necessarily is a hyperlink :)